# How to position a single child node so it is in the same level with parent using forest?

Tags: forest, trees

Here is my tree diagram built using forest package.

[image: forest tree]

How to move the node in the red pen to the position of the blue pen?

Here is my code.

```
\begin{forest}
    for tree={calign=last},
    [HEAD
        [tag,no edge]
        [branch
            [commit
                [commit
                    [tree
                        [tree
                            [tree
                                [tree
                                    [blob]]
                                [blob]]
                            [blob]]]]
                [tree
                    [tree
                        % [shared blob here]
                        [tree
                            % [shared blob here]
                            [blob]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Hi @Bobyandbob, I'm new here and I'm also a newbie in LaTeX. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding the second "commit" as a child of first "commit" node you can insert it at the same level with them.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={calign=last},
    [HEAD
        [tag,no edge]
        [branch
            [commit,no edge,tikz={\draw()--(!n);}
                    [tree
                        [tree
                            [tree
                                [tree
                                    [blob]]
                                [blob]]
                            [blob]]]]
            [commit
                [tree
                    [tree
                        % [shared blob here]
                        [tree
                            % [shared blob here]
                            [blob]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! +1. This is the first time I've encountered the syntax `tikz={\draw()--(!n);` Did it come from tikz or forest? Can you tell me where I can find documentation about it? If not, can you explain it?

Comment: First forest is a pgf/TikZ-based package, you can add a tikz code at any level with key `tikz` or at the end of tree (before `\end{forest}`), for '()' in `\draw()` it refere to the current node  and `(!n)` to the next  sibling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I looked for documentation on the TikZ manual version 3.0.1a as well as the manual 1.18 on `\draw()` and this notation is used without being documented. On the other hand, the notation `(!n)` is neither used nor documented. Do you know in which version of Tikz these codes are documented?

Comment: Those notations are from forest not from tikz  
http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf

Comment: The notation `\draw()` is documented in the forest manual. It is used in the **tikz manual** on page **748**, but is **not** documented anywhere in the tikz manual. It is documented in forest, we agree. On the other hand, the notation `(!n)` is **not** documented in forest (at least I didn't find it) or in tikz. Do you have any documentation of this notation `(!n)` and if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Take a look at the forest manual pages 8 and 57.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Indeed, I found the explanations on p 8, I quote `It is possible to refer to other nodes which stand in some (most often geometrical) relation to the current node. To do this, follow the node’s name with a ! and a nodewalk specification` Can you add these explanations to your answer with references in order to make it easier to understand?